# PushNotificationActionPerformed listener not firing on iOS when application is running in backgroud

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I'm using Capacitor(v2) Push Notifications into my app. I've follow the capacitor tutorial from capacitor website, and implemented this code:

```
// Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
PushNotifications.register();

// On succcess, we should be able to receive notifications
PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
  console.log('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
});

// Some issue with our setup and push will not work
PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
  console.log('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
  this.showToast('Erro ao ativar as notificações push.');
});

// Show us the notification payload if the app is open on our device
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification: PushNotification) => { 
  this.showToast(notification.title + '\n' + notification.body);
  this.addNewNotification(notification);
});

// Method called when tapping on a notification
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
  this.addNewNotification(notification.notification.data); 
});
```